# Java jar version

Tags: java, gradle, jar

How to create the jar with version number in gradle. I have the build script in gradle which creating the jar. I need to generate the jar with version number. How to achieve it using gradle script

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use add the below script

```
jar {
    version='1.0'
}
```

So that it will generate the jar with version

Answer (score 2):

`Gradle` will build your archive with the following pattern by default:

```
[baseName]-[appendix]-[version]-[classifier].[extension]
```

if `archiveName` has not been explicitly set.

`version` - The version part of the archive name, if any.

Applying:

```
jar {
    baseName = 'app'
    version='1.0'
}
```

Will specify the base name and the version to your archive:

```
app-1.0.jar
```